# ViewModel Property Change has no effect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

i'm working with ASP.NET MVC at the moment and I found something with the viewModels that I do not understand. I woked out a very simple example, where this happens:

I have a simple view model with one Property:

```
public class Testmodel
{
    public int Test { get; set; }
    public Testmodel()
    {
        Test = 0;
    }
}
```

and I want to change the property in my controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Models.ViewModels.Testmodel model)
    {
        model.Test += 1;
        return View(model);
    }
```

In my View, the effect of the change is only visible, when I access the property directly, not when i use Data Binding. The view looks like this:

```
@model hobble.Models.ViewModels.Testmodell
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Startseite";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<p>It is @Model.Test</p>   

<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Test" />
}
```

In the Text-Part, where I directly access the Model.Test property, I get the Update, but in the Editor field, I don't. I would expect that everytime I click the Submit-Button the Test Property is increased by one, but that is not Happening. 
Can someone explain to me, what I got wrong about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because whenever you return an object from a `POST`, in MVC, it is assuming that you are doing that because there was a validation error so instead of filling the form with the model values in your controller MVC is grabbing the values from the `ModelState`.

The quick "solution" is to use `ModelState.Clear()` but this is not recommend since you are basically ignoring MVC built-in functionality.

You could, as you already noticed, not use the Html Helpers or look into using the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Using `ModelState.Clear()`, just in case you want to ignore the "do-not-use-this-workaround" warning:

```
public ActionResult Index(Testmodel model)
{
    model.Test++;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. I'll try to use the "correct" way. It's quite confusing at the beginning :D